# get click event of each rectangle inside canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, click

I dont know how to register click event on each rectangle.

here is the sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/9WWqG/1/

Comment: This post may be helpful: https://medium.com/devtravel/hit-region-detection-for-html5-canvas-and-how-to-listen-to-click-events-on-canvas-shapes-815034d7e9f8#.wgzhx52ns

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're basically going to have to track where your rectangles are on the canvas, then set up an event listener on the canvas itself. From there you can take the coordinates of the click event and go through all your rectangles to test for 'collisions'.

Here's an example of doing just that: http://jsfiddle.net/9WWqG/2/

html:

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```

javascript:

```js
// get canvas element.
var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

function collides(rects, x, y) {
    var isCollision = false;
    for (var i = 0, len = rects.length; i < len; i++) {
        var left = rects[i].x, right = rects[i].x+rects[i].w;
        var top = rects[i].y, bottom = rects[i].y+rects[i].h;
        if (right >= x
            && left <= x
            && bottom >= y
            && top <= y) {
            isCollision = rects[i];
        }
    }
    return isCollision;
}

// check if context exist
if (elem && elem.getContext) {
    // list of rectangles to render
    var rects = [{x: 0, y: 0, w: 50, h: 50},
                 {x: 75, y: 0, w: 50, h: 50}];
  // get context
  var context = elem.getContext('2d');
  if (context) {

      for (var i = 0, len = rects.length; i < len; i++) {
        context.fillRect(rects[i].x, rects[i].y, rects[i].w, rects[i].h);
      }

  }
    
    // listener, using W3C style for example    
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log('click: ' + e.offsetX + '/' + e.offsetY);
        var rect = collides(rects, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        if (rect) {
            console.log('collision: ' + rect.x + '/' + rect.y);
        } else {
            console.log('no collision');
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer..but your collides function was not working when there are more than one rectangle in canvas... I have modified as below and it worked...

Comment: How could you do it with circles or something?

Comment: @user10124491, check the distance of the click from the center of the circle. If that distance is less than the radius of the circle, it's inside.

Answer (score 18):

This is an old question but what was once hard to do when it was posted is now much easier.

There are many libraries that keep track of the position of your objects that were drawn on canvas and handle all of the complexities of handling mouse interactions. See [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS),
[KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com/),
[Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) or
[Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) and this [comparison of canvas libraries](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE) for more.

You can also take a different approach and use
[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) and [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)
to have a solution that uses SVG and VML instead of canvas and works even on IE6.

Your example changed to use Raphaël would look like this:

```js
var r = Raphael(0, 0, 300, 150);

r.rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
    .attr({fill: "#000"})
    .click(function () {
        alert('first rectangle clicked');
     });
    
r.rect(75, 0, 50, 50)
    .attr({fill: "#000"})
    .click(function () {
        alert('second rectangle clicked');
     });
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9WWqG/491/).

#### Update 2015

You may also be able to use [ART](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/art), a retained mode vector drawing API for HTML5 canvas - see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134238/is-there-a-javascript-library-for-paint-like-applications-using-canvas/14524118#14524118) for more info.

Comment: I have 4 dynamic donut charts on a page which are created dynamically,I need to put a clickable text in the center of each which could be clicked. Any Idea please?

Question asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243032/event-handler-on-center-of-doughnut-chart-using-chart-js

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to make this work in mozilla using the **clientX,clientY** instead of offsetX/offsetY.

Also, if your canvas extends beyond the `innerHeight`, and uses the scroll, add the `window.pageYOffset` to the `e.clientY`. Goes the same way, if your canvas extends beyond the width.

Another example is at my github: https://github.com/michaelBenin/fi-test

Here is another link that explains this: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/02/13/finding-out-the-mouse-click-position-on-a-canvas-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Please use below function if you want to support more than one rectangle in canvas and handle its click event..... modified logic given by Matt King.

```js
function collides(myRect, x, y) {
    var isCollision = false;
    for (var i = 0, len = myRect.length; i < len; i++) {
        var left = myRect[i].x, right = myRect[i].x+myRect[i].w;
        var top = myRect[i].y, bottom = myRect[i].y+myRect[i].h;
       if ((left + right) >= x
            && left <= x
            && (top +bottom) >= y
            && top <= y) {
            isCollision = json.Major[i];
        }
        }
    }
    return isCollision;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below function if you want to support more than one rectangle in canvas and handle its click event

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1125" height="668" style="border: 3px solid #ccc; margin:0;padding:0;" />
```

```js
  var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
    elemLeft = elem.offsetLeft,
    elemTop = elem.offsetTop,
    context = elem.getContext('2d'),
    elements = [];

    // Add event listener for `click` events.
    elem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       // var leftWidth = $("#leftPane").css("width")

      //  var x = event.pageX - (elemLeft + parseInt(leftWidth) + 220),
       //     y = event.pageY - (elemTop + 15);

            var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
        y = event.pageY - elemTop;

        elements.forEach(function (element) {
            if (y > element.top && y < element.top + element.height && x > element.left && x < element.left + element.width) {
                alert(element.text);
            }
        });
    }, false);



    // Set the value content (x,y) axis
    var x = 15, y = 20, maxWidth = elem.getAttribute("width"),
        maxHeight = elem.getAttribute("height"), type = 'TL',
        width = 50, height = 60, text = "", topy = 0, leftx = 0;



    for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        y = 10;
        for (j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
            width = 50, height = 60
            switch (j) {
                case 1:
                    type = 'TL'; // Trailer
                    height = 60;
                    width = 85;
                    text = i + 'E';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    type = 'DR'; // Door
                    height = 35;
                    width = 85;
                    text = i;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    type = 'FL'; // Floor
                    height = 30;
                    width = 40;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    type = 'FL'; // Floor
                    height = 30;
                    width = 40;
                    y -= 10;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    type = 'DR'; // Door
                    height = 35;
                    width = 85;
                    text = i*10 + 1;
                    y = topy;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    type = 'TL'; // Trailer
                    height = 60;
                    width = 85;
                    text = i + 'F';
                    y += 5;
                    break;
            }

            topy = y;
            leftx = x;
            if (type == 'FL') {
                for (k = 1; k <= 12; k++) {
                    elements.push({
                        colour: '#05EFFF',
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        top: topy,
                        left: leftx,
                        text: k,
                        textColour: '#fff',
                        type: type
                    });

                    if (k % 2 == 0) {
                        topy = y + elements[j - 1].height + 5;
                        leftx = x;
                        y = topy;
                    }
                    else {
                        topy = y;
                        leftx = x + elements[j - 1].width + 5;
                    }
                }
                x = leftx;
                y = topy;
            }
            else {
                elements.push({
                    colour: '#05EFFF',
                    width: width,
                    height: height,
                    top: y,
                    left: x,
                    text: text,
                    textColour: '#fff',
                    type: type
                });
            }

            //get the y axis for next content
            y = y + elements[j-1].height + 6
            if (y >= maxHeight - elements[j-1].height) {
                break;
            }
        }
        //get the x axis for next content
        x = x + elements[0].width + 15
        if (x >= maxWidth - elements[0].width) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Render elements.
    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        context.font = "14pt Arial";
        context.strokeStyle = "#000";
        context.rect(element.left, element.top, element.width, element.height);
        if (element.type == 'FL') {
            context.fillText(element.text, element.left + element.width / 4, element.top + element.height / 1.5);
        }
        else {
            context.fillText(element.text, element.left + element.width / 2.5, element.top + element.height / 1.5);
        }
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.stroke()
    });
```

Here's an example of doing just that: http://jsfiddle.net/BmeKr/1291/