# Create a random circle and then do something once that circle is clicked

Tags: javascript, onclick, html5-canvas

I can create the random circle fine, but I want the circle to be created and when the circle is clicked, the score to be increased and a new circle is made.

I have already tried using an `addEventListener` but that doesn't work as it throws an error, I have also tried using a `circle.onclick = function() {blah}` but that doesn't do anything at all, not even throws an error.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", function() {
    createGameCircle();
});

function createGameCircle() {
    radius = 20;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var circle = [
        context.beginPath(),
        rand_x = Math.random(1) * max,
        rand_y = Math.random(1) * max,
        context.arc(rand_x, rand_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI),
        context.fill(),
        context.closePath()
    ];

    circle;

    circle.onclick = function() {
        score++;
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = (score);
        createGameCircle();
    }
}
```

So with this code, when the circle is clicked I expected a new one to be made again randomly, and a score to be added on. But nothing happens at all, as well no errors are thrown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get click event of each rectangle inside canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014851/get-click-event-of-each-rectangle-inside-canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code requires a bit of rework, however it can work.

I've assumed your code sets the value for max somewhere? Anywho: You need to set the Event Listener to canvas and remember on creation of the circle where it was created (note that this will still work as a box, but it should get you started)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv")
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var elements = [];

document.getElementById("startGame").addEventListener("click", function() {
    createGameCircle();
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
        y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
            var dx = element.rand_x - x;
            var dy = element.rand_y - y;
            if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= element.radius * element.radius) {
            createGameCircle();
        }
    });
});
function createGameCircle() {

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    elements.pop();

    var circle = {
        rand_x: Math.random(1) * max,
        rand_y: Math.random(1) * max,
        radius: 20
    };

    elements.push(circle);    

    context.beginPath(),
    context.arc(circle.rand_x, circle.rand_y, circle.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI),
    context.fill(),
    context.closePath()
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hcqsjzfu/1/ for a working test

Edit: fixed an error
Edit 2: Working example now only triggering when the click happens in the actual circle (A.K.A I did the math logic for you)

Answer (score 0):

Your `circle` variable isn't a DOM element that has an `onClick` property, it's an array - and an array being used in a very odd way at that.

When you do `circle.onclick = function()...`, you're just adding a function to the already-abused array, a function that will never be invoked by a click.

You need an entirely different approach. There are a number of ways you could go. One of them would be to make an object like `{x: rand_x, y: rand_y, radius}`, and push that object onto an array that stores all of the circles that you've created.

Then add an `onclick` function *to your canvas*, which is a DOM element which can receive clicks, and have your `onclick` function loop through the array (in reverse order so the most recent circles have priority) checking if clicks are inside each circle.